# Can I slow down HDD's writing speed/the motors inside it?

Tags: hard-disk

My HDD makes an annoying noise even when Windows's disk usage is about 30%. Is there any way to slow down the HDD to make it silent? Either software side or "hands on". Thanks

Comment: Depends on when your drive was made. There's "Automatic acoustic management" which you can change with e.g. HDDScan (https://hddscan.com/), but that may be deprecated on more current drives.
In any case, you'll probably find more helpful answers on a more appropriate SE site, such as Super User.
Also, make sure to check your S.M.A.R.T. values. Excessive noise may be an indicator of a drive starting to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Forget this nonsense about slowing down a hard drive.
Buy a SSD or NVMe drive and its totally silent, faster, and uses less power.